# Can I use htmlspecialchars($email, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') instead of filter_sanitize_email()

Tags: php, security, xss

I am very confident with htmlspecialchars() for sanitizing user-inputted data as mentioned in the title. But for sanitizing emails, can I still use it, instead of FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL()? Provided I have already used FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using htmlspecialchars on user input is a method to prevent XSS attacks and it is a way to be safe **when you output** data, not when you save it.

Say an user submits this:

```
<span onclick="alert('evil script')">something that seems normal</span>
```

You would want to save the content exactly how the user submitted it. But when you display it you should use [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) (or [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities)) to turn some special characters into entities to prevent browsers from interpreting them.

the **FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL** flag used on one of the functions in the [filter extension](http://php.net/filter) is a way to validate user data and that's a process that needs to be done **before** you save user data.

More details on preventing xss you can find [here](http://www.sunnytuts.com/article/preventing-cross-site-scripting-xss)

Comment: How about when I am making a contact form, in which a user enters his name and email, before sending the mail using the mail() function I use htmlspecialchars() on the $_POST['name'], but what about $_POST['email']? what should I use on it before sending the email? filter_validate, filter_sanitize or the same htmlspecialchars()?

Comment: @SameerZahid if you want to send an email to that address you should try to be as sure as possible that the email address is valid. So you should use FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL to validate the format. Using htmlspecialchars changes some characters and that might mean that you could change the email address making it invalid (even if I don't think there's a real chance of having those characters in the email address).

Comment: No I want the person to specify his email, while sending submitting a contact form on my website... which will be send to my email, not his.

Comment: even if you can't tell for sure if a certain email address exists (and that would be an overkill anyway) another step you can take is to extract the domain name (example.com from tester@example.com) and to check it using this function: http://php.net/checkdnsrr

Comment: @SameerZahid it's still a good idea to have the email address only validated.. you don't want to transform it, you just want to be sure that what they typed is an email address (or at least seems to be)

Comment: See I don't care about the user's email. I just don't want him to send me code on my email_address :p. So I want to sanitize it with htmlspecialchars() as with other data.

Comment: @SameerZahid that's your choice.. but the point of my answer was that `htmlspecialchars` is not a function used to sanitize user input, it is a function used to clean the output you make on a html page. So the entire idea of sanitizing with this function is a bit wrong as it does things that are not needed for sanitizing and doesn't do some that are

Answer (score 3):

`FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL` ensures that a string is an email address.

`htmlspecialchars` makes a string safe for inserting into HTML.

They are completely different things and are not alternatives for each other under any circumstances.

Comment: I thought FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL checks weather a string is an email or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Provided I have already used FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL
```

Then how is the string going to contain anything other then an email if you have already validated it.

If you are going to output the given email back even if validation fails then yes you should use `htmlspecialchars()` on the email string or just notify that its not a valid email.

Comment: what is it is a valid email address but contains tags? like: <&akfjas@website.com. Is this not a valid email?